# What kind of CMS I should use for these features?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, content-management-system

I need a light CMS for .NET 3.5/C#/SQL Server with these features:

1. Create/Edit Pages/Subpages in different languages
2. Associate Photos to a page

Does anyone know of a good CMS that can do these? I don't want to build my own, if there are good alternatives already out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DotNetNuke http://www.dotnetnuke.com/

You can set up multiple languages: http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Video-Library/Viewer/VideoId/33/How-To-Setup-Multiple-Languages.aspx

There are many options for displaying images http://www.dnncreative.com/WorkingwithimagesinDotNetNuke/tabid/137/Default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest - http://umbraco.com/

Comment: uhm, umbraco is for mvc! I works with WebForms...